# Custom Notification Sound not working in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android-notifications

I copied an mp3 file in the Android Studio's res > raw folder. I'm trying to show a notification with a custom sound when the onReceive method of the BroadcastReceiver class is called. The notification is being shown but the problem is the sound is not playing when the notification is shown.

Here Is My Code:

```
    public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID = "admin_channel";
    private static final String TAG = "ALARM_RECEIVER_TAG";

    private AlarmManagerUtils alarmManagerUtils;

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: ");


        alarmManagerUtils = new AlarmManagerUtils(context);

        int alarmNotificationId = intent.getIntExtra("AlarmNotificationId", 0);
        String alarmName = intent.getStringExtra("AlarmName");
        long currentTimeMillis = Utils.currentTimeMillis();
        long alarmTimeTimeMillis = intent.getLongExtra("AlarmTime", 0);
        String formattedCurrentTime = Utils.formatTimeStampToTime12(currentTimeMillis);
        String formattedAlarmTime = Utils.formatTimeStampToTime12(alarmTimeTimeMillis);
        Uri alarmSoundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.athan_fajr);
        

        showNotification(context, alarmNotificationId, context.getString(R.string.prayer_name_isha), "Its time for " + context.getString(R.string.prayer_name_isha) + " " + formattedAlarmTime, alarmSoundUri);

    }

    private void showNotification(Context context, int alarmNotificationId, String title, String description, Uri alarmSoundUri) {
        Log.d(TAG, "showNotification: alarmSoundUri: "+alarmSoundUri);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        //Necessary to display on android Oreo and above
        createNotificationChannel(notificationManager, alarmSoundUri);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.side_nav_mosque)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(description)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(alarmSoundUri)
                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000});

        notificationManager.notify(alarmNotificationId, builder.build());
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel(NotificationManager notificationManager, Uri alarmSoundUri) {
        Log.d(TAG, "createNotificationChannel: ");

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .build();

            //this name will show when user click settings after swiping notification
            CharSequence name = "Personal Notification";
            String description = "Include all the personal notifications";

            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationChannel.setDescription(description);
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.setSound(alarmSoundUri, attributes); // This is IMPORTANT

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
    }

}
```